# how to load .vbs files which are stored in c drive into uft 11.5 or 12.0

Tags: function, vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I have some code that I have written in VBScript and is stored as a .vbs file in my C:\ drive. How can I use that code in my UFT program?

Comment: Can you put that code along with your question??

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do with this *code*, you can [add it to your test as a function library](https://softwaretesttips.com/2014/06/24/loadassociate-a-function-library-vbs-txt-qfl-for-use-with-a-script/), then its contents will be available for use in the test.

Answer (score 0):

In your UFT program (GUItest) you can use the option of "Associate Function Library" by right clicking your test [Associate Function Library in UFT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axp3S.jpg). After selecting the option you can select your .vbs file and the functions in that file will be available for use